# How can I change the style of multiple elements using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

I have one CSS style sheet with rules like this:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, .contentheading, .title{

 font-size: 13px ;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-family: Arial, Geneva, Helvetica, sans-serif ;
}
```

The tags, classes are generated by plugin so i can't add a single class to it.

So, is there any way that I can change the styles of all elements at once, at runtime, that doesn't involve going through them one by one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do multiple selectors in jQuery just like in Css. Maybe not the best performance-wise but will work.

```
$('h1, h2, h3, h4, .contentheading, .title').css('color', 'red');
$('h1, h2, h3, h4, .contentheading, .title').addClass('someOtherClass');
```

Comment: Instead of doing the lookup twice, it would perform better to chain your method calls: `$('h1...').css('color', 'red').addClass('someOtherClass');`

Comment: it was an example to show thats how to apply css to all those elements or to apply a class.....

Comment: May I know what impact on performance do we have If we used this?

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple with jQuery. Simply use the selectors in question as your jQuery selectors, then change the css. So the JavaScript/jQuery code would be this, assuming you wanted to change the `font-size` and `font-weight`:

```
$('h1, h2, h3, h4, .contentheading, .title').css({
  'font-size': '17px',
  'font-weight': 'bold'
});
```

It sounds like you're new to jQuery, you probably want to get familiar with the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) and [api](http://api.jquery.com/) sites.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS:

```
* {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Arial, Geneva, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way where i can get the current font-size of all elements and then increase by one

Comment: Yes. Just iterate over each element.  Two problems though.  It can be expensive if the DOM is big, and the size does not have to be a px, it could be a pt, em or % too. That makes your job that bit harder.  Why would you want to do this in JavaScript anyway?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('h1,h2,h3,h4,.contentheading,.title').css({ 'color': '#fff' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is tagged jQuery, using the `*` selector should help you to get all elements. Then you can use the `css` method to change the styles.

```
$('*').css();
```

In CSS you can just use the same `*` selector to apply some styles to all elements, but make sure you put it last of the CSS file so as to override all other rules.

```
* {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Arial, Geneva, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```