# Change css of multiple elements

Tags: jquery

I just want to know if instead of

```
$(".element1").css('background','#000');
$(".element2").css('background','#000');
```

It is possible to concatinate multiple elements to have them affected by one command or if there is a more efficient way like so:

```
$(".element1",".element2").css('background','#000');
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836527/how-can-i-change-the-style-of-multiple-elements-using-jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142637/jquery-css-to-multiple-elements http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306279/change-or-swap-the-css-of-multiple-html-elements-at-once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106353/targeting-multiple-elements-with-jquery and _loads_ more

Comment: I was under pressure and did a quick search. I did not find what I was looking for, so I made the mistake of not checking the documentation. I apologize for the redundant question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

CSS selectors have always supported unions:

```
$(".element1, .element2").css('background','#000');
```

You can also add to the jQuery element set yourself:

```
$(".element1").add(".element2").css('background','#000');
```

**All you needed was a cursory glance at [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).**

Answer (score 3):

`$(".element1,.element2").css('background','#000');` will do